# Converting Dynamic PHP output to PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I want to convert my dynamic PHP output to PDF, i've looked for the answers but couldn't find useful answers. I've used mPDF but it wasn't much useful for me.

Comment: You can combine the output buffering abilities of php with a PDF output library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dompdf, you can download it from [here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/O3IyajP6ce/dompdf.html).

Store your output in some variables and use below code

usage

```
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$html = "<html><body>". $dynamic_output_variable ."
</body></html>";
$pdf = new DOMPDF();
$pdf->load_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$output = $pdf->output();
file_put_contents('output folder/file name.pdf', $output);
$pdf->stream('file name.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DomPdf library. You can simply download the latest version of this library using URL: https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/detail?name=dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.tar.gz&can=2&q=

This latest version support many fonts.

Include the library using below code:

```
require_once("/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

View the pdf output in browser:

```
$html = "Your dynamic php output";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$preview = $dompdf->stream("dompdf.pdf", array('Attachment' => 0));
echo $preview;die;
```

Get PDF as a string using below code:

```
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

You can make it downloadable using the below code:

```
$filepath//full path of your temporary/public location;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($filepath, $pdf); // save the pdf file on server
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: 'attachment'; filename='dompdf.pdf'");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($filepath);
exit();
```